# Can I store template argument value i for int2type<i>?

Tags: c++, templates, type-erasure

I have various different data types.  Would like to store them in a vector/tree (e.g. a directory structure of data), but at some point I need to get the real type and operate on the actual type.  e.g. print them out by doing boost::fusion::for_each on each class's member.  I've looked at the following choices of solutions:

1. boost::variant -- there is a limit of 50 types.  I got more, like hundreds, possibly grow to thousand.
2. virtual+inheritance -- I could have another interface class that is constructed based on type T, and store interface base class that has virtual functions to act on the real types.  But then I have to write 1 virtual function for each action.  It also becomes messy on double dispatching.
3. Read about Int2Type idiom.  Can I do something similar?

I've attempted the following.  Is there any ways I can pass in the template  value from somewhere in the last loop?  Not sure how to store that.  It's kind of a chicken-egg problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct NullType {};
struct A {};
struct B {};

template <int i=0>
struct Int2Class
{
        typedef NullType Type;
};

template <> struct Int2Class<1>
{
        typedef A Type;
};

template <> struct Int2Class<2>
{
        typedef B Type;
};

struct Base
{
        virtual ~Base() {}
};

template <typename T>
struct Data : public Base
{
        Data() {}
        Data( const T& t ) : t_( t ) {}
        T t_;
};

template <typename T>
void ft( const T& t )
{
        // do something specific to T
}

int main()
{
        A a;
        B b;
        Base* d1 = new Data<A>( a );
        Base* d2 = new Data<B>( b );

        std::vector<Base*> v;
        v.push_back( d1 );
        v.push_back( d2 );

        Data<A>* a1 = static_cast<Data<A>*>( d1 );
        if( a1 ) cout << "yeah\n";

        typedef Data<Int2Class<1>::Type>* Type;
        Data<A> *a2 = static_cast<Type>( d1 );
        if( a2 ) cout << "yeah2\n";

        for( std::vector<Base*>::iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end();
++i )
        {
                // for illustration purpose, items in vector is in the order
                // of the class Id #, or save that as part of a pair in the
                // vector

                typedef Data<Int2Class<???>::Type>* Type;
                ft( static_cast<Type>( *i ) );
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need 1000s of types?  What kimds of operations?  What kinds of types?

Comment: @Yakk it'll be up to the user of the library to define their class types.  As of now, it'll be <100 class types.  But there will be more in the future.  Imagine these classes will be holding data members, then one operator would be to BOOST_ADAPT_STRUCT the class, and do a boost::fusion::for_each to display their member values.

Comment: ... what else?  Just display?  Then type erase a display method.  What you are describing is serious overkil to just print members.